# I am getting circular template inheritance detected error in log due to that my sitecore instance is not running

Tags: sitecore

I am getting circular template inheritance detected error in log due to that my sitecore instance is not running
I tried multiple ways but didn't get any possible solution
here is the screen shot of log error
and apppool is also getting stopped
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3tuq.png)

I tried to reset the IIS and some services I stopped and restarted.
but nothing is working